# Obj-C, how can I log to a file how long a method took in seconds?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I envisage I'll run into problems as i haven't done this before.
I'm thinking that I can either define a date at the start of the method or initialise a class.

Then at the end of the method, call the commit method, which will write the time taken about with some sort of code to determine where the measurement was made.

Comment: Call `NSLog` before and after calling your method, and subtract the timestamps.

Comment: This reminds me of `dtrace` not being available on iOS... Its a shame, it would be perfect to solve this problem =/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well I need to run this on a device which is crashing, then send the file at the end, not sure where its crashing, but its due to the time it takes to run.

Comment: If you have the device in hand, just pull the logs in Xcode. If you don't (it's in the field or whatever), TestFlightApp is one of the best ways to get the logs from crashing devices. Then you don't have to build any special infrastructure for it.

Comment: @RobNapier - thanks for your input, I have had the user send me her crash logs, but all it says `failed to launch in time` and nothing else. Its definitely some database processing I', doing in app delegate, however I need to find out where its slow. I did have TestFlight on the app, but the data never gets written back to the TF server.

Comment: Hmmm, it would be nice if i didn't have to call start just.. `LogTime *lt = [[LogTime alloc] autorelease];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're crashing before the app finishes launching, so no code is going to fix this. If TestFlightApp isn't working, any other code-based solutions are likely to have the same problem.

As @dasblinkenlight noted, NSLog timestamps, so that's a really easy first step. Then you need to get the logs.

If possible, have your user install and run the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465). Have her connect her device and select it from the Devices list. Then select Console and "Save Console As..." She can then mail it to you.

[image: iPhone Configuration Utility]

Comment: What a shame all users don't have macs

Comment: The link referenced includes the link for the Windows version of iCU.